# Error after inserting data in spinner's adapter

Tags: android, spinner

I have a problem that I have a two spinner's on one screen, Both are filled after JSON parsing and second spinner is filled after selecting item from first spinner; I want; first time when we open the screen then spinner shows Select keyword but when we want to change selected item in first spinner then it shows all parsed data. but after attempting to do that I received an error message. I don't know How it will be removed? I wish a kind favour of you regarding this subject.

**Error:**

```
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:298)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:351)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:189)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:148)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:112)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1238)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1044)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-19 14:27:39.103: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(807):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code is here

```
package com.equinix.android.sitevisit;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.equinix.android.adapter.SiteVisit_CagesAdapter;
import com.equinix.android.adapter.SiteVisit_IBXAdapter;
import com.equinix.android.common.LoginScreen;
import com.equinix.android.common.MenuScreen;
import com.equinix.android.common.R;
import com.equinix.android.parsing.Parse_Json;
import com.equinix.android.servicecall.Service_Call;

public class Site_Visit_Details extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     ImageButton _siteVisit_Home, _siteVisit_Logout, _siteVisit_AddVisitor, _siteVisit_StartDateButton, _siteVisit_EndDateButton, _siteVisit_Next, _siteVisit_CheckBox;
     EditText _siteVisit_StartDate, _siteVisit_EndDate, _siteVisit_AdditionalInfo;
     Spinner _siteVisit_IBX, _siteVisit_Cage;
     ArrayAdapter statusAdapter;
     Bundle bundle;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
    private int flagValue, checkBoxFlag=0;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    public static int count=0;
    public static ArrayList<String> cage_Id = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> cage_Name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> cage_NaturalKey = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static boolean flag_cages = false;
    public static ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> lastName = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> companyName = new ArrayList<String>();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.site_visit_details);

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();


        _siteVisit_Home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home);
        _siteVisit_Logout = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.logout);
        _siteVisit_AddVisitor = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addVisitorImageButton);
        _siteVisit_StartDateButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.startDateImageButton);
        _siteVisit_EndDateButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.endDateImageButton);
        _siteVisit_Next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.nextImageButton);
        _siteVisit_CheckBox =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        _siteVisit_StartDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.startDateEditText);
        _siteVisit_EndDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.endDateEditText);
        _siteVisit_AdditionalInfo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.additionalInformationEditText);

        _siteVisit_IBX = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ibxSpinner);
        _siteVisit_Cage = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.cageSpinner);
        LoginScreen.name.add("Select");
        statusAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , LoginScreen.name);//Sets an status adapter
        statusAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        _siteVisit_IBX.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
        _siteVisit_Cage.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
        //Get Data from Parsing
        try{
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://122.180.114.68/eqixmobile/siteservice/um/ibx");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{\"credentials\":{\"username\":\"mobileuser1\",\"password\":\"welcome1\"}}");
    /*  HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.9/DEVELOPMENT/VERSIONED/Equinix/trunk/iphone/login");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{\"ibx\":{\"credentials\":{\"password\":\"welcome1\",\"userid\":\"mobileuser1\"}}}");*/

        final Service_Call obj = new Service_Call(post, se, "mobileuser1", "welcome1",false);
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Site_Visit_Details.this, "   EQUINIX                   ", "Loading....   ", true);

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {

           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    statusAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   dialog.dismiss();

              }
           };

           final Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

               public void run() {

                   LoginScreen.name.clear();                                
                   String json_string = obj.call_Service();
                   new Parse_Json(json_string).parse();
                   handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
               }
           };
           checkUpdate.start();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      /*    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,MenuScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/

        //statusAdapter.add(LoginScreen.name);
        SiteVisit_IBXAdapter adapter = new SiteVisit_IBXAdapter(LoginScreen.name, this);


        if(bundle.getInt("screen_flag")!=0)
        {
        try{
            prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String savedIBXString = prefs.getString("savedIBXString",null);
        String savedCagesString = prefs.getString("savedCagesString", null);
        String startDate = prefs.getString("startDate", null);
        String endDate= prefs.getString("endDate", null);
        String addInfo = prefs.getString("additionalInfo", null);
        _siteVisit_StartDate.setText(startDate);
        _siteVisit_EndDate.setText(endDate);
        _siteVisit_AdditionalInfo.setText(addInfo);
        for(int i=0;i<LoginScreen.name.size();i++)
        {
            if(savedIBXString.equals(_siteVisit_IBX.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()))
            {
                _siteVisit_IBX.setSelection(i);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<cage_Name.size();i++)
        {
            if(savedCagesString.equals(_siteVisit_Cage.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()))
            {
                _siteVisit_Cage.setSelection(i);
            }
        }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
        _siteVisit_Home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Site_Visit_Details.this, MenuScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        try {

                firstName = bundle.getStringArrayList("FirstName");
                lastName = bundle.getStringArrayList("LastName");
                companyName = bundle.getStringArrayList("Company");

                for(int i=0; i<firstName.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println("Name is ======== "+firstName.get(i)+" "+lastName.get(i)+" Company name=====>> "+companyName.get(i));
                }

        } catch (Exception e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        _siteVisit_Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Site_Visit_Details.this, LoginScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        _siteVisit_Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
                System.out.println(" Size of ArrayList is  "+firstName.size());
                if(firstName.size()!=0){
                    if((_siteVisit_StartDate.getText().toString().length()!=0) &&(_siteVisit_EndDate.getText().toString().length()!=0))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Site_Visit_Details.this, Site_Visit_Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("IBXName", _siteVisit_IBX.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("CagesName", _siteVisit_Cage.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("StartDate", _siteVisit_StartDate.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("EndDate", _siteVisit_EndDate.getText().toString());
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("FirstName", firstName);
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("LastName", lastName);
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Company", companyName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Site_Visit_Details.this, "Please fill all mandatory field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Site_Visit_Details.this).create();
                       alertDialog.setTitle("EQUINIX");
                       alertDialog.setMessage("Please Add Visitor First");
                       alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                               return;
                           }
                       });

                       alertDialog.show();
                }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Site_Visit_Details.this, "Please select add visitor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        _siteVisit_IBX.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            /**
             * Called when a new item was selected (in the Spinner)
             */
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
                try{
                    arrayList_clear();
                    SiteVisit_IBXAdapter adapter = new SiteVisit_IBXAdapter(LoginScreen.name, Site_Visit_Details.this);
                    _siteVisit_IBX.setAdapter(adapter);
                    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getBaseContext());
                     SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
                  prefEditor.putString("savedValue",_siteVisit_IBX.getSelectedItem().toString());

                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://122.180.114.68/eqixmobile/siteservice/um/cages");
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{\"ibx\":{\"credentials\":{\"username\":\"mobileuser1\",\"password\":\"welcome1\"},\"userkey\":\"68782\",\"permissionCode\":\"PLACE_BASIC_SERVICES\",\"id\":\""+LoginScreen.id.get(pos)+"\",\"name\":\""+LoginScreen.name.get(pos)+"\",\"naturalKey\":\""+LoginScreen.naturalKey.get(pos)+"\"}}");
                final Service_Call obj = new Service_Call(post, se, "mobileuser1", "welcome1",false);
            /*String json_Response = obj.call_Service();
                new Parse_Json(json_Response).parse_Cages();*/
                    /*SiteVisit_CagesAdapter adapter = new SiteVisit_CagesAdapter(Site_Visit_Details.cage_Name, Site_Visit_Details.this);

                    _siteVisit_Cage.setAdapter(adapter);*/

                    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Site_Visit_Details.this, "EQUINIX     ", "Loading....   ", true);

                    final Handler handler = new Handler() {

                       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                            SiteVisit_CagesAdapter adapter = new SiteVisit_CagesAdapter(Site_Visit_Details.cage_Name, Site_Visit_Details.this);

                            _siteVisit_Cage.setAdapter(adapter);
                               dialog.dismiss();

                          }
                       };

                       final Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

                           public void run() {

                               String json_Response = obj.call_Service();
                                new Parse_Json(json_Response).parse_Cages();
                               handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                           }
                       };
                       checkUpdate.start();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            private void arrayList_clear() {
                Site_Visit_Details.cage_Id.clear();
                Site_Visit_Details.cage_Name.clear();
                Site_Visit_Details.cage_NaturalKey.clear();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
              // Do nothing.
            }
        });

        _siteVisit_Cage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            /**
             * Called when a new item was selected (in the Spinner)
             */
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
                   prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getBaseContext());
                   SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
                prefEditor.putString("savedCagesString",_siteVisit_Cage.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


            }
        });
        _siteVisit_StartDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                flagValue = 0;
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);


            }
        });

        _siteVisit_EndDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                flagValue = 1;
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        });

        _siteVisit_AddVisitor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Site_Visit_Details.this, Site_Visit_AddVisitor.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        _siteVisit_CheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(checkBoxFlag==0){
                    _siteVisit_CheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_box_checked);
                    checkBoxFlag=1;
                }else{
                    _siteVisit_CheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_box_unchecked);
                    checkBoxFlag=0;
                }

            }
        });


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay(flagValue);
            }
        };

    private void updateDisplay(int flag) {
        if(flag==0){
        _siteVisit_StartDate.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                    .append(mDay).append("/")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
        }
        else{
            _siteVisit_EndDate.setText(
                    new StringBuilder()
                            // Month is 0 based so add 1
                            .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                            .append(mDay).append("/")
                            .append(mYear).append(" "));
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putString("savedIBXString", _siteVisit_IBX.getSelectedItem().toString());
      editor.putString("savedCagesString", _siteVisit_Cage.getSelectedItem().toString());
      editor.putString("startDate", _siteVisit_StartDate.getText().toString());
      editor.putString("endDate", _siteVisit_EndDate.getText().toString());
      editor.putString("additionalInfo", _siteVisit_AdditionalInfo.getText().toString());
      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: but how to ask a question from your account?

Comment: @nik: Code was available but was not well formed.

Comment: @Adil Soomro i understand i get it

Answer (score 0):

Check the ArrayList object that you're inserting in the adapter if it's not empty, use Logs, and double-click on the Error in your LogCat to re-direct you to the line of code that you're getting an error.